# Is there any way to make the application not restart at each @Test while running the android UI tests, but run all the testcases without restarting?

Tags: android, android-activity, automated-tests, android-espresso, instrumented-test

In the app I'm testing during onboarding there are tutorial screens that I want to test in separate @Tests, but between tests the app quits and restarts and this causes the tutorial to skip and jump to the main screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> between tests the app quits and restarts and this causes the tutorial to skip and jump to the main screen.

Instead of trying to force the testing framework to not restart the app (which would be bad because you want tests to be consistent and not carry over state from other tests), design your tests such that the tutorial is not skipped.

So - what is making your tutorial be skipped? It's not the restarting of the app, it's logic you've coded. Maybe you have a preference set when you've gone through the tutorial once to not show it again?

Whatever it is, write your test such that the setup phase puts the app in the state you need it to be in to do the test. If your setting a preference to skip the tutorial, you'd clear that preference before starting your test, for example.